# How I can shorten this title length?

Tags: php

I'm using WordPress as my CMS and one of the components of my site is master slider. It's a plugin to display posts in a slider. It takes the full post titles and puts them in the slider. I want to shorten this title. This code is generating the title:

```
$value = $post->post_title;
```

How I need to modify this code to get the title's first 25 characters and then add '...' to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is in a plugin, you don't actually want to directly modify the plugin file itself. If you do that, you won't ever be able to update the plugin without overwriting your work and needing to find it and add what you did again.

Instead, there's a [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) set up in the plugin for exactly this situation:

```
// in the plugin file:
function msp_get_template_tag_value( /* variables */ ) {
  // ... other stuff we don't care about
  // line 1037:
  return apply_filters( 'masterslider_get_template_tag_value', $value, $tag_name, $post, $args );
}
```

Line 1037 is a filter, which means you can modify what the plugin creates and replace it with whatever output you want. To do that, add the following in your functions.php file in your theme:

```
add_filter('masterslider_get_template_tag_value', 'wpse183153_shorten_master_slider_title', 10, 4);
function wpse183153_shorten_master_slider_title($value, $tag_name, $post, $args){
  if ( 'title' != $tag_name ) {
    return $value;
  }

  $short_title = $value;
  if( strlen($value) > 50) {
    $short_title = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $value, 50));
    $short_title = $short_title[0] . '...';
  }
  return $short_title;
}
```

This function checks to see if the current tag being edited is the title. If it isn't, then it just skips and lets the content be what it was. If it is the title, then it checks to see if the value is longer than 50 characters; if it is, then it truncates that value and appends '...'.

Comment: sorry, that dont works for me. or I dont know how to put this code correctly..     case 'title':
   $value = $post->post_title;
   break; I have this and i need to modify it to shorten title. THANKS!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried in the original question please? With some of the context of the code around it?

Comment: I' noob so I will try to show you everything I can..

this is  case 'title':
   $value = $post->post_title;
   break;

the code which controls title when I;m deleting it title is dissapearing. Some kind peaople said to me try to fix my problem with this way.

function truncateShort($text, $chars = 25) {
     $text = $text." ";
     $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
     $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
     $text = $text."...";
     return $text;
}
Then use this:

  $title = $post->post_title;
  $value = truncateShort($title, 50};

Comment: also , <?php
    $value = $post->post_title;
    if (strlen($value) > 30) {
        echo substr($value, 0, 30) . '...';
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
?>

this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433961/how-i-can-shorten-this-title-lenght/29434520#29434520  that is my question in oter sector, nothing of this is working..

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0cm4i9dncyaaw8/msp-functions.php?dl=0 this is the file and this code is on 867 line..

Comment: maybe it can help you to find out what coe i need to input..

Comment: Mkay, it looks like that plugin has a filter for that value. I'll update my answer in a few minutes to match what's happening and give you something that will work.

Comment: Updated. You should be able to use that exactly as-is, just copy and paste it into your functions.php file in your theme.

Comment: If this works for you, please remember to mark this answer as correct (the little checkmark to the left)

Comment: Bro, I'm adding this first code in the plugins file i uploaded at the bottom and when I dot his, site is dissapearing.(((

// in the plugin file:
function msp_get_template_tag_value( /* variables */ ) {
  // ... other stuff we don't care about
  // line 1037:
  return apply_filters( 'masterslider_get_template_tag_value', $value, $tag_name, $post, $args );
}

Comment: I do it wrong?(

Comment: Now i placed it on 1037 and it site is still dissapearing...maybe this theme was created in the strange way..

Comment: WOW , I copied this function phph code you wrote and it works!!!!!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I cant vote up, i need 15t reputation, I will do this when i get this 15 reputation . THANKS A LOT AGAIN!!!!!

Comment: You don't have to vote up, but marking as correct would be good - the checkmark just below the 'vote up' arrow. It might be hard to see unless you hover over it.

Comment: I marked it! god bless you man ^^

Comment: I'm a lady :D No problem.